# Python 3 - ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, windows

This ones really baffling me. I'm trying to edit a python script (hue-flux.py) that originally called another python script (sun.py) to return a value as part of its process. The objective is that sun.py runs independently, creates a txt file with two values on two lines (two values total) that master.py reads instead of calling sun.py for it. Essentially they are sunrise and sunset times. I've succeeded in getting sun.py to write the values, but when trying to get hue-flux.py to read the txt file for the values instead of calling sun.py I'm getting errors.

Here was the original code before I edited:

```
sunrise_time = sun.get_sun(location)[0]
print (sunrise_time)
sunset_time = sun.get_sun(location)[1]  # Sunset time in 24hr format
print (sunset_time)
fadetime = get_secs_to_hour(sunset_time)
```

and the code after edit:

```
with open("c:\\users\\snipped\\suntimes.txt", mode='r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    sunrise_time = lines[0]
    sunset_time = lines[1]  # Sunset time in 24hr format
    print ((sunrise_time),end = '')
    print ((sunset_time),end = '')
sunrisefadetime = get_secs_to_hour(sunrise_time)
print (sunrisefadetime)
sunsetfadetime = get_secs_to_hour(sunset_time)
```

and here's what I get when I try and run the edited code:

```
====================== RESTART: C:\Python36\hue-flux.py ======================
Discovering Hue bridges...
Found previously connected bridge
7:13
17:34Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\hue-flux.py", line 290, in <module>
    sunrisefadetime = get_secs_to_hour(sunrise_time)
  File "C:\Python36\hue-flux.py", line 254, in get_secs_to_hour
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(today + hour, "%x%H:%M")) - time.time()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 559, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 

>>>
```

Can anyone offer any help? OS is Windows Server 2012 R2. The original script is at https://github.com/KpaBap/hue-flux though the original author doesn't seem to be responding.

Comment: As you can see from the output, there's a trailing newline character in `sunrise_time`. Try `get_secs_to_hour(sunrise_time.strip())`.

Comment: That's fixed it cheers!!